# Distributing currency/number across multiple items in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, floating-point, currency

So I have a sort of payment splitter and I'm struggling with floating point operations. I'm using currency.js to handle the maths and have jQuery installed too, though probably won't use it in the example below

I want someone to be able to pay an amount (let's say $50) and spread that amount across all the items in the list, and subtract it.

So say I have a list of prices

```
prices = [12, 8, 25, 14, 12, 20, 0.5, 8] 
grandTotal = sumArray(prices) //Returns 99.50
```

Then a customer wants to apply $50 to that invoice, and I want to spread the amount out evenly across all items. So in short I want to do 99.5-50 = 49.5

```
amountToPay = 50
```

What I want is to output something like this:

```
/*This sums to 50 and is what need to be subtracted.
In this case I've added the remainder to the last item, but would like the spread to be as even as possible. In currency format, so two decimal places of precision*/
toSubtract = [6, 4, 12.5, 7, 6, 10, 0.25, 4.25]

/*This sums to 49.5, the amount left over when toSubtract is subtracted from prices*/
newPrices = [6, 4, 12.5, 7, 6, 10, 0.25, 3.75]
```

But yeah, really not sure how to even approach distribution. I have attempted to it by calculating the percentage (e.g 50/99.5), but it was extremely messy and still had precision & rounding errors everywhere and I was manually catching each one and it was just gross and incomprehensible.

Comment: Yep, I've already attempted that more or less with a foreach. The floating points don't convert to currency, and if I do use currency.js() to do so, I ended up with calculations that were always off. Will try with that exact dataset and see if I wasn't making a  mistake previously. EDIT: yeah, it comes out to 49.99, so I need to add that extra .01 somewhere

Comment: Yes, or just the prices to subtract will do. So the same basic array you just gave me is great, but I need to get it to two decimal places of precision that still add up to 50 even, which means some remainders have to be distributed, and every time I try to manually correct for the remainders, it breaks with a different set of numbers

Comment: E.g if the array was [0.333333, 0.333333, 0.333333] it would need to finish as [0.34, 0.33, 0.33]

Comment: I would suggest not using JavaScript to do anything with currency unless you first multiple all operands by an order of magnitude equal to the maximum precision you desire and treat them numbers as integers. Or use one of the many libraries out there that are made for these kinds of things.

Comment: As mentioned in post, I am using currency.js for operations, and it has has a great distribute() function that is unfortunately not valid here, but I have used in other parts of the app and is my inspiration. I just left it out for simplicity's sake for the example.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your info, you can do simple math to calculate the partial amounts left.

```
total = 99.50;
amount = 50.00;
prices = [12, 8, 25, 14, 12, 20, 0.5, 8];
rate = (total - amount) / total;
newPrices = prices.map(e => ((e * rate).toFixed(2)));
```

```
["5.97", "3.98", "12.44", "6.96", "5.97", "9.95", "0.25", "3.98"]
```

Comment: Thanks! But doesn't distribute evenly, though does work in that example. If you sub in amount = `31.5` the total will be 0.01 off. Now if the maximum margin of error is only 0.01, then that's not really a major problem as I can simply check that the sum of the final output is equal to what's expected, get the difference and then add that to the last key. However I'm not sure how to test that as I have tried a few different ways and ended up with fairly substantial variations. I will play around with this in the morning, I can't see why it shouldn't work but I'm cautious.

Comment: Of course some rounding error will occur. But I do not understand what you mean with it is not evenly distributed. Can you give an example? From the given data my code and results look totally correct. [example](https://i.ibb.co/4S4zHk7/image.png)